# Complement of halting problem Co-RE or non R.E

Tags: computability, halting-problem

Can someone please tell me if complement of halting problem(L) is Co-RE or non R.E ?

I think that it is Co-RE as L' (L complement) is R.E but everywhere its given non R.E

Comment: Have you tried *proving* your claim? There's a one-line proof (assuming one Lemma with a simple proof).

Comment: In the duplicate link its mentioned not R.E . But halting problem is R.E so its complement should be co-R.E right?

Comment: Being non-RE and co-RE are two separate things that are not mutually exclusive. One is trivial, the other potentially not.

Comment: I understand the meaning of Co-R.E. I am just not able to understand how is L non R.E too.

Comment: As one of the duplicates mentions, if a question is RE and co-RE, it's also in R (simple proof which you should do for your learning). So if you know it's not in R, it must be outside of at least one of the two.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is surely not recursive. I was just confused whether it is Co-RE or Non R.E.

Comment: As I've been trying to tell you, it *can be both*.

Comment: How can it be both ? If it is non R.E then Machine will not halt on both "yes" and "no" cases but for Co re it will halt on only "no" cases.

Comment: No; check the definitions. It's not about individual machines, but problems (that is the *existence* of certain machines, which does not preclude other machines). The complement of the Halting problem/language is, famously, not r.e. but co-r.e..

Comment: I am not able to get what do you mean to say. Is complement of halting problem unrecognizable (not r.e.) or co-recognizable (co-r.e.) or both? I feel both. If we run input TM on input w which is not in TM language, then we never know whether it will halt or not in the future as it will keep running, so unrecognizable (not r.e.). Its co-recognizable (co-r.e.) simply because halting problem is recognizable. Am I right with this?